# Win 7 - Libraries empty

Tags: windows-7, user-folders

So, I went in and changed just the Icons on these folders:
My Documents
My Pictures
My Music
My Movies

When I did, a lock appeared there and I couldn't access the folders. I turned my UAC all the way off and restarted my PC, I can now get into them, but they are all empty. What could have caused this and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are these folders located in the filesystem, i.e., is it `c:\users\<username>\documents`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% what you did but try this and let me know what happens:

1. Right click on the start menu and choose properties
2. Select the Start Menu Tab and click the customize button
3. Scroll down until you see the options for "Personal Folder" and set it to Display as Link if it's not already and press OK, OK to get out of the dialogs.
4. click on your start menu and there should be an item at the top of the right column named with your user name.  click that and it will open an explorer window to all your current special folders.
5. For each of them (contacts, Desktop, Downloads, Favorites, Links, My Documents, My Music, My Pictures, My videos, Saved Games, and Searches) right click an choose properties then pick the location tab and click the "Restore Default" button.  If you see a message pop-up that says: "This folder doesn't exist. Would you like to create it?" click yes.  If you get a message that pop-up that says: "do you want to move all the files from the old location to the new location?" click yes to that too.

That should fix it.  It's probably similar to the way you were trying to edit the icons in the first place but the key here is to you use the EXACT steps I listed to make sure you get to the folder's current location and not a copy of it that you may have created by accident.

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies, I really appreciate it, I was asking for a friend and it turns out she had backed up her stuff onto her external drive and completely forgot she had done it so she thought all her stuff was completely emplty.